# stack.ToList() – order of elements?

Tags: c#, .net, list, stack

When using the `.ToList()` extension method on a `Stack<T>`, is the result the same as popping each element and adding to a new list (reverse of what was pushed)?

If so, is this because it really is iterating over each element, or does it store the elements in reverse internally and slip the array into a new `List<T>`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Stack` itself does not have a `ToList` method, it's the extension method from the `Enumerable` class. As those extension methods only deal with `IEnumerable<T>`, it's safe to assume that `ToList` iterates over the items of the stack to create the new list (or at least acts exactly as if it would - the `Enumerable` methods sometimes test the type of the argument and use an optimized implementation).

Interestingly the documentation does not seem to directly state which order the stack is enumerated in, but the example code does show an order and the examples are part of the documentation. Also, in practice changing the iteration order would break so much code that it would be way too risky to change now.

I also checked with Reflector; `Stack<T>` stores its items in an array with the bottommost element at index 0, but its `Enumerator` iterates the array *in reverse order*. Therefore the first element that comes out of the iterator is the top of the stack.

Comment: Why is it safe to assume that? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation that states in which order the Enumerator for `Stack<T>` iterates, but maybe I haven't look well enough...

Comment: It doesn't say it outright (at least not at the moment), but the example with [the documentation for `Stack.GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfw8w9at%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) shows a last-to-first order, and the stack reversal operations in the example wouldn't work if this ordering weren't used (oops; as Jon Skeet said in his answer).

Answer (score 9):

`ToList` will iterate in the same order as if you did this:

```
foreach (T item in stack)
```

The [docs for `GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfw8w9at(v=VS.100).aspx) don't explicitly state the order as far as I can tell, but the example shows that it will iterate as if it were popping. So if you push 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 then `ToList` will give you 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.