# Stack and Queue enumeration order

Tags: c#, .net

I know that `List` enumerator guarantees the enumeration order and respects last sort operation, I know that the `Dictionary` and `HashSet` ones do not i.e. you can **NOT** be sure that

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = ...;

foreach(var pair in dictionary)
{

}
```

will process pairs in the order they were appended.

What about the `Stack` and the `Queue`? Do their enumerators guarantee any order?

Comment: You are comparing different things.  Stacks, queues, arrays, lists,  have a strong ordering guarantee while dictionary has none. Have you encountered a specific problem?

Comment: I found [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628048/stack-tolist-in-net-order-of-elements)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, I did not. But this is irrelevant. To tell the truth for a few years you youth I used the `Dictionary` enumeration and the code was built so that it was dependant on the enumeration order and it was awful. I did never stumble upon a case when `Dictionary` changes the order of enumeration. This does not make the mistake more awful.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for the tip. It's close but not close enough. I need a documented evidence of order for enumeration to be sure. Mere observation is not good.

Comment: RE: dictionaries: the only time a dictionary _might_ change the order is when the `Dictionary` is resized.  The reason enumeration is undefined is because it is in an internal hash order (GetHashCode() is further hashed into a finite number of buckets).

Comment: @BerinLoritsch This does not seem to be true. Try building an example where you fill a dictionary one way and it enumerates another. I tried and failed. It's not as easy as you say. There has to be something more than a simple internal resize.

Comment: Key word: _might_.  However, the implementation of how things are enumerated in a dictionary is intentionally undefined.  It is free to change from version to version of .Net.  The classes are really stable now, so even that is unlikely but theoretically possible.

Comment: The order isn't explicitly stated because MS is incompetent, but it is strongly implied by both the documentation, which includes examples, and the code. Obviously the order of the enumeration will always be LIFO and worrying about it changing is silly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For `Stack`, the enumeration is currently done by a nested private class called `StackEnumerator` (this is from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs,c8a4d13ea4b1a95a)):

```
private class StackEnumerator : IEnumerator, ICloneable
{
    private Stack _stack;
    private int _index;
    private int _version;
    private Object currentElement;

    internal StackEnumerator(Stack stack) {
        _stack = stack;
        _version = _stack._version;
        _index = -2;
        currentElement = null;
    }

    public Object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public virtual bool MoveNext() {
        bool retval;
        if (_version != _stack._version) throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString(ResId.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion));
        if (_index == -2) {  // First call to enumerator.
            _index = _stack._size-1;
            retval = ( _index >= 0);
            if (retval)
                currentElement = _stack._array[_index];
            return retval;
        }
        if (_index == -1) {  // End of enumeration.
            return false;
        }

        retval = (--_index >= 0);
        if (retval)
            currentElement = _stack._array[_index];
        else
            currentElement = null;
        return retval;
    }

    public virtual Object Current {
        get {
            if (_index == -2) throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString(ResId.InvalidOperation_EnumNotStarted));
            if (_index == -1) throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString(ResId.InvalidOperation_EnumEnded));
            return currentElement;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Reset() {
        if (_version != _stack._version) throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString(ResId.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion));
        _index = -2;
        currentElement = null;
    }
}
```

Note how it enumerates starting with the index set to `_stack._size-1` and decrements the index to return each element in LIFO order.

**However, because this is not documented you can't guarantee that it will always be this way** (although it would be insane for Microsoft to change the way that the enumerator works now!)

You can inspect the implementation of the nested `QueueEnumerator` class and similarly determine that the enumeration is done in the order in which items would be dequeued.

**The Stack.GetEnumerator() *strongly implies* that LIFO order is used.**

If you look at [the example for `Stack<T>.GetEnumerator()` in Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfw8w9at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and inspect the stated output, you can see that it is in LIFO order.

This strongly suggests that Microsoft fully intend a Stack to be enumerated in LIFO order - but they forgot (or didn't bother to) to explicitly document this!

Comment: I get your point. `Strongly implies` is at least something. I will fish for additional answers for a little before accepting this answer. Best atm.

Comment: I posted an issue on GitHub about the enumeration order of the `Stack<T>` collection [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68317 "Is the enumeration order of the Stack<T> collection well defined?"), and the feedback I got was *"this is very much by design"*. So the LIFO enumeration order is pretty much guaranteed.

Answer (score 11):

A [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) is a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) collection (says so right in the documentation).  That means the enumerator gives you the items in the order that they were added.

A [Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) is a Last-In-First-Out (LIFO) collection.  That means the enumerator gives you the items in reverse order of how they were added.

Stacks and Queues are very standard Computer Science constructs, so they really can't be re-purposed without serious backlash.  When you look at the examples for the `GetEnumerator()` functions, it clearly documents the order of enumeration:

[Stack Enumeration:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfw8w9at(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    Stack<string> numbers = new Stack<string>();
    numbers.Push("one");
    numbers.Push("two");
    numbers.Push("three");
    numbers.Push("four");
    numbers.Push("five");

    // A stack can be enumerated without disturbing its contents.
    foreach( string number in numbers )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }

    /* This code example produces the following output:

     five
     four
     three
     two
     one

    */
```

[Queue Enumeration:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a9449ty(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    Queue<string> numbers = new Queue<string>();
    numbers.Enqueue("one");
    numbers.Enqueue("two");
    numbers.Enqueue("three");
    numbers.Enqueue("four");
    numbers.Enqueue("five");

    // A queue can be enumerated without disturbing its contents.
    foreach( string number in numbers )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }

    /* This code example produces the following output:

     one
     two
     three
     four
     five

    */
```

Again, with basic computer science definitions, An enumerator or iterator must present the elements in the natural order for a collection.  Specific collection types have a defined order.

**Caveat**

Please note that while the enumeration process does reflect the natural order of the FIFO and LIFO collections ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collection_(abstract_data_type))), this is not how Queues ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type))) and Stacks ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))) are *intended* to be used.  They are intended to be used with the `Enqueue()`/`Dequeue()`and `Push()`/`Pop()`/`Peek()` interactions.  Microsoft includes the enumerator to keep everything consistent with the base `ICollection<T>` interface, and keeps the enumerator in the collection's natural order.

The purpose of a Queue is to provide a pipeline of work that can be processed in order.  The purpose of a Stack is to provide a way of returning to a previous context when the local work is done.  They are intended to work on one item at a time.  Iterating over the collection with an enumerator kind of side steps that whole purpose and does not remove items from the queue/stack.  It's essentially a peek at all the items that are there.

Comment: I think the question here relates to the behaviour of the enumerator not being explicitly documented. Sure, `.Push()`, `.Pop()`, `.Enqueue()` and `.Dequeue()` have well-defined behaviour - but they are not the enumerator.

Comment: @MatthewWatson You get my point. I need something more than a logical implication to rely upon.

Comment: Take a look at the documented behavior for Stack `GetEnumerator()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfw8w9at(v=vs.110).aspx  It documents that the enumeration is in the stated order for the collection.  If the enumerator returned elements in an order that was not normal for the collection, it would be a bug.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch That's what MatthewWatson brought up in his answer.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Why `Peek` is OK for how the things are intended to be used and enumerating is not? What's the big difference? Yes, I would be glad to have a `Peek` with an index, why not?

Comment: I've added references in the last section that go into a lot more detail as to the computer science intentions behind the abstract data types.  If you think of Queue and Stack as a pile of work, then you realize they are meant to have work added and removed in a set order.  Looking at the size or content of the backlog would merely be an added feature--but not necessarily what the construct was made for.

Comment: As to `Peek`, it's commonly used in data processing to see if we are ready to work on that particular pending item or not--or even to see if there is a pending item.  It only looks at the item at the top of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It doesn't seem to be explicitly documented, but elements are enumerated in the same order as if you popped/dequeued them.

Comment: Is there any documented evidence for that?

Comment: @ZverevEugene, just checked MSDN, it doesn't seem to be mentioned.

Comment: @ZverevEugene Right near the top of [the documentation for Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it says`Represents a first-in, first-out collection of objects`. Similarly for Stack it says `Represents a simple last-in-first-out (LIFO) non-generic collection of objects`

Comment: @MatthewWatson indeed; it just doesn't explicitly state that it affects the enumeration order.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Well... maybe check the reference source.

Comment: @ZverevEugene It doesn't *have* to be explicitly documented - FIFO/LIFO is the basic behaviour of Stack and Queue.

Comment: Reference source is implementation details, not documentation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen if enumeration of a LIFO or FIFO structure didn't return objects in LIFO/FIFO order, it would be a very serious bug.

Comment: I would agree with that, edited my comment, the primary idea I had to say was that referencesource isn't documentation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree it isn't documentation - and the only way to know if Microsoft intend to never change the behaviour is for them to document it. However, the chances of them changing the way it works now is close to zero.