# Why does Stack<T> class in C# allow ElementAt(index) while it is an ADT?

Tags: c#, data-structures, stack, adt

Stack is an Abstract Data Type (ADT) and it is supposed to have a sealed list of operations like Push(), Pop(), Peek(),... to enforce Last-In-First-Out (LIFO) Principle.

But it has ElementAt(index) that allows me to access any element in the stack. On my understanding, Stack should have less visibility on the elements which are not in the surface. Isn't it?

Comment: `Stack<T>` does not _have_ an `ElementAt()` method. It implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and for this there is the **linq** extension `ElementAt()`. But that can't _change_ the stack (you may change the properties of the element, but not the reference in the stack), so I don't see a problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Stack is an Abstract Data Type (ADT)

That is true for the general concept of Stack, but `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<T>` never promises to be (just) an ADT.

It has to provide the ADT functionality as a minimum (to live up to the name) but is free to offer more.

So it makes no attempt to hide Contains(), Count, TryPeek(),  etc.

Answer (score 6):

`ElementAt()` is provided via Linq's [`Enumerable.ElementAt()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx), not via the `Stack<T>` interface.

This works because `Stack<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` which is all that is needed to implement `ElementAt()` since all it does is to iterate through all the elements provided via `IEnumerable<T>` until N of them have been accessed.

For a `Stack<T>` this is an O(N) operation. If you use `ElementAt()` with, say, a `List<T>` then an internal optimisation turns it into an O(1) operation.

As to why `Stack<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` - only one of the designers can really answer this question. Since it is a non-mutating operation then it doesn't really violate anything fundamental about the stack. I would *guess* that it was provided as a convenience.

As /u/Damien_The_Unbeliever points out in his answer, code could determine the Nth element without the IEnumerable interface by popping N elements to another stack and then pushing them all back in reverse order so that the original stack is unchanged.

The fly in the ointment here is that Microsoft *does not document* the order in which Stack's `IEnumerable` returns its elements. You can inspect the source code to see that it does indeed return the elements in LIFO order - but that is simply not documented.

This is discussed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37725773/106159).

In any case, where is the ADT interface defined for the abstract stack that you're talking about? I don't think there's a definitive answer for that. Strictly speaking, you could say that a stack only has `Push()` and `Pop()`. And yet most implementations also provide `Count`.

As [the article about Stack on Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Non-essential_operations):

> In many implementations, a stack has more operations than "push" and "pop". An example is "top of stack", or "peek", which observes the top-most element without removing it from the stack.
>
> Since this can be done with a "pop" and a "push" with the same data, it is not essential. An underflow condition can occur in the "stack top" operation if the stack is empty, the same as "pop". Also, implementations often have a function which just returns whether the stack is empty.

So fundamentally the answer to your question is:

**The library designers decided to add some non-mutating convenience methods in addition to just having the mutating methods `Push()` and `Pop()`.**

Comment: Then OP might ask why stack implements `IEnumerable`, since it's also not part of contract implied by theoretical stack structure.

Answer (score 3):

In pseudo-code, here's an `ElementAt` that is external to `Stack` and only uses the ADT operations:

```
T ElementAt<T>(Stack<T> items, int index)
{
    var tmp = new Stack<T>();
    while(!items.Empty && index > 0)
    {
       tmp.Push(items.Peek());
       items.Pop();
       index --
    }
    try {
        return items.Peek(); //Presumed to throw an appropriate exception if empty
    }
    finally {
       while(!tmp.Empty)
       {
          items.Push(tmp.Peek());
          tmp.Pop();
       }
    }
}
```

(The above assumes mutating `Stack`s - a slightly different implementation would work for immutable stacks and wouldn't need the clumsy undo action)

Of course, the fact of the matter is that the `Stack` type in .NET is build for *practical problem solving*, not for some abstract purity, and (by dint of the `Stack` offering to allow enumeration), a more *efficient* implementation is actually available here. And we don't force people to copy such methods into a "utils" library.